# Figure with subfigures and table as label in latex

Tags: graphics, subfloats

[image] How do I create such an image in latex ? That is a table with subfigures and tables as label.

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: The `subcaption` package might help.

Comment: You can try to paint the images using TikZ, but it would be a lot of work. Maybe it would be easier to draw the images with a painting program and include them using `graphicx`. You can use three sub-figures inside a single `figure`, e.g., using `subcaption` package. For each sub-figure you could use, e.g., a `tabular` with three columns or some `minipage`s or `\parbox`es. You may even use a TikZ `matrix`.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/happy/happy1}}{\tableCaption h i j}    \qquad  
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/happy/happy2}}{\tableCaption h i j}    \qquad
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/happy/happy3}}{\tableCaption h i j} \\

    \bigskip
    \caption*{The caption without a number}
    \bigskip

    \footnotesize
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/neutral/neutral1}}{\tableCaption h i j}    \qquad  
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/neutral/neutral2}}{\tableCaption h i j}    \qquad
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/neutral/neutral3}}{\tableCaption h i j}

    \bigskip
    \caption*{The caption without a number}
    \bigskip

    \footnotesize
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/sad/sad1}}{\tableCaption h i j}    \qquad  
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/sad/sad2}}{\tableCaption h i j}    \qquad
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{gfx/dataSet/ourDataset/sad/sad3}}{\tableCaption h i j}

    \bigskip
    \caption*{The caption without a number}

    \caption{Sample Results}
\end{figure}
```

Also these commands.

```
\newcommand \tableCaption[3]{ 
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
         first  & #1 \\
         second  & #2 \\    
         third  & #3 \\ 
     \end{tabular}
}

\usepackage{stackengine}
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit overcomplicated...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill  
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Bugs}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill  
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Flies}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill  
        \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption*{test\\ text\\ text}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Dinos}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{Welcome to animal kingdom}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be my solution with the `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[textfont=bf]{subcaption} % bold text in sub caption 

\captionsetup{labelfont=bf} % bold label

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section} % include section number in caption of figure

\begin{document}

\section{Sectiontitle}

\begin{figure}[h]\centering\small

    \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} \\
            Text 1.1 & Text 2.1 & Text 3.1 \\
            Text 1.2 & Text 2.2 & Text 3.2 \\
            Text 1.3 & Text 2.3 & Text 3.3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{caption}
    \vspace{2\tabcolsep}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} \\
            Text 1.1 & Text 2.1 & Text 3.1 \\
            Text 1.2 & Text 2.2 & Text 3.2 \\
            Text 1.3 & Text 2.3 & Text 3.3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{caption}
    \vspace{2\tabcolsep}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} \\
            Text 1.1 & Text 2.1 & Text 3.1 \\
            Text 1.2 & Text 2.2 & Text 3.2 \\
            Text 1.3 & Text 2.3 & Text 3.3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{caption}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{the main caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Made some changes to closely match the style to the picture.

[image]